# Variance of projected data

Tags: machine-learning, variance, pca, linear-algebra

What's the expression for the variance of projection of $N$ data points onto a vector $\mathbf{v}$ which is **not necessarily a unit vector**? I could only find an expression when $\mathbf{v}$ is taken to be a unit vector.

**Here's my attempt**

Let's say our data is represented by a matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times p}$ and is already centered, i.e. $\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} (\mathbf{x}_1 - \bar{\mathbf{x}})^\intercal \\ \vdots \\ (\mathbf{x}_N - \bar{\mathbf{x}})^\intercal \end{bmatrix}$, where $\bar{\mathbf{x}} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{x}_i$.

The projection for each data point is $\frac{\mathbf{x}_i^\intercal\mathbf{v}}{\mathbf{v}^\intercal\mathbf{v}}$. The variance can then be computed as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\sigma}^2 &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \Big(\frac{\mathbf{x}_i^\intercal\mathbf{v}}{\mathbf{v}^\intercal\mathbf{v}} - \frac{\bar{\mathbf{x}}^\intercal\mathbf{v}}{\mathbf{v}^\intercal\mathbf{v}} \Big)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{N} \frac{1}{(\mathbf{v}^\intercal\mathbf{v})^2}\big(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{v}\big)^\intercal\big(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{v}\big) \\
&= \frac{1}{N} \frac{\mathbf{v}^\intercal\mathbf{X}^\intercal\mathbf{X}\mathbf{v}}{(\mathbf{v}^\intercal\mathbf{v})^2} \\
&= \frac{\mathbf{v}^\intercal \mathbf{S}\mathbf{v}}{(\mathbf{v}^\intercal\mathbf{v})^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\mathbf{S}$ is the covariance matrix of the original data.

**Is this correct?** I am using it as an intermediate step in another [problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/518992/first-principal-component-direction) and the expression I derived above for variance of projected data doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection of $x$ onto the span of $v$ is a vector $\frac{x^\top v}{v^\top v} v$, but this vector has length $\frac{x^\top v}{v^\top v} \|v\| = \frac{x^\top v}{\sqrt{v^\top v}}$, which is what you should be using in your definition of variance. This will lead to $\frac{v^\top S v}{v^\top v}$ as the expression for variance (notice that replacing $v$ by $2v$ would not change this expression, but your expression $\frac{v^\top S v}{(v^\top v)^2}$ would get halved), and will lead to the desired result in your other post, as you noted in the comment.