# Maximize Variance of Linear Combination of Matrix Columns

Tags: probability, variance, pca

Let $A$ be a $k \times 1$ random vector, and $\mathbf{A}$ be a $n \times k$ matrix of observations.

Letting $t \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ be a vector of weights s.t. $||t||_2 = 1$, suppose we are interested in maximizing the variance of a linear combination of the columns of $\mathbf{A}$, i.e. $\mathbf{A}t$. I have read that this can be written as solving
$$ \max_{||t||_2 = 1} \frac{t'(\mathbf{A' A})t}{t't}$$

---

However I'm a bit confused about where this came from. Would the problem not be solving the following instead?
$$ \max_{||t||_2=1} \quad \text{Var}(\mathbf{A}t) = t'\text{Var}(\mathbf{A})t = t'(\mathbb{E}[AA'] - \mathbb{E}[A]\mathbb{E}[A'])t $$
Replacing the expectations with the sample analogue yields,
\begin{align*}
\max_{||t||_2=1} \quad &t'\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n A_i A_i' - (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n A_i) (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i') \right)t \\
 &\propto t'\left( \mathbf{A'A} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i \sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i' \right)t \\
 &= t'\left( \mathbf{A'A} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_i A_j' \right)t
\end{align*}

where $A_i$ is the $i$th row of observed $\mathbf{A}$. In the formulation above, a) what happened to the term involving the double summation and b) where did the $t't$ in the denominator come from?

If we further assumed $\mathbf{A}$ has mean 0, then I can see how a) drops out though that doesn't address b), and the formulation above also does not seem to mention the requirement of de-meaning.

Comment: people tend to assume that data are centered when discussing these kinds of things, and this is the resolution to your (second) point (a). Regarding your (first) point (b), we need to divide by the length of $t$, or find some different way of normalizing, otherwise we can get arbitrarily large variances by just making $t$ very big.

Comment: The $t^\prime t$ was never in the denominator, because under your restriction $||t||_2=1,$ it was identically equal to $1.$

Comment: Thanks! I have figured it out with your hints. The original formulation should've been written as $\max_{t \neq 0}...$, and only applies if $\mathbf{A}$ is mean 0. The point (a) then drops out, and to get the denominator, we can for instance apply a Lagrangian to the constraint $||t||_2=1$.

Comment: For further discussion of some the points raised here, see my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/301561/919 (on whether the PCA optimization problem is convex).