# Special PCA which minimizes the variances explained

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, pca

Lets say I want to do a different version of PCA, in which I **minimize** the variances explained.

So lets say I find the first such variance minimizing axis $PC^{'}_1$. Then I impose the orthogonality constraint and find the second variance minimizing axis $PC^{'}_2$ and so on, to get $PC^{'}_1, PC^{'}_2,...,PC^{'}_n$.

And suppose the standard principal components in the descending order of variances explained are given by $PC_1, PC_2, ..., PC_n $.

So is it always true that $PC_i = PC^{'}_{n+1-i}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$?

If the answer is yes, then how can we prove it? 
And if the answer is no, how can we compute the aforementioned decomposition?

Comment: Could you please tell us what you mean by a "variance explained" and how it differs from the usual sense of "variance"?  As far as minimizing variances goes, that's a numerically fraught approach indeed: it's generally hard to find such a direction when the variances in all other directions are larger.  As a theoretical matter, when all the eigenvalues are distinct it shouldn't matter. Proof: minimizing the variances corresponds to *maximizing* variances in the inverse of the covariance matrix.

Comment: The answer is yes, we prove it using the Courant-Fischer minimax thm; see the second equation in the "Min-max principle for singular values" subsection of the section "Applications" of its wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_principle_for_singular_values

Comment: Variance explained just refers to the partial sum of the first m eigenvalues, eg '90% of the variance is explained by the first five principal components '

Comment: @seanv507 The problem is that minimizing the "variances explained" amounts to selecting the zero vector for every PC *ad infinitum* according to the recipe given here! That problem does not occur in the usual setting of successive maximization subject to the orthogonality constraints.

Comment: @whuber I imagined that the OP was implicitly assuming a minimization over unit vectors, as is typical in PCA.

Comment: @John One would hope so!  But that's not what the post actually says, so it seems worth pointing out -- that's one less bug to find.  Moreover, it doesn't have to be done that way: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/301561/919 for an alternative formulation.